# Why is there a diference in the quality of embeded swf symbols between mx.image and spark.image

Tags: apache-flex, image, flash, flex4.5

I have embebed .swf symbols in my flex 4.5 application like so:

```
<s:Image source="@Embed(source='GaugeSkin.swf', symbol='reflection')"/>
```

and they look awful! even when with "smooth=true"

```
<s:Image source="@Embed(source='GaugeSkin.swf', symbol='reflection')" smooth="true"/>
```

But, if i use the "old" mx component:

```
<mx:Image source="@Embed(source='GaugeSkin.swf', symbol='reflection')"/>
```

The image looks beautiful, like it should.
Anyone knows why is this?
should i use the mx component to get the quality i need/want?

**Edit:** added images

[image: side to side ugly comparison]

Comment: I'd love to see screenshots and/or a running sample.

Comment: Smoothing will only work with bitmap images.  What are the symbols that you're using?  What do you consider as being 'beautiful'?

Comment: @J_A_X I think the s:Image component turns everything into a bitmap image. If you look at the "imageDisplay" property of spark's image it's a spark primitive: bitmapImage. I haven't looked at it in detail, but perhaps that's the difference between the Spark and MX components?

Comment: Is this an svg?  My gut instinct is telling me that it might be converting it to bitmap a bit too early.  Have you tried setting the width/height? How about setting the smooth quality to high?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the "smoothingQuality" style to "high".

```
<s:Image source="..." smooth="true" smoothingQuality="high"/>
```

Internally, s:Image and mx:Image are entirely different. MX Image extends `SWFLoader` and that does most of the work. s:Image has a spark `bitmapImage` component in its skin that does most of the work. I don't know exactly what properties are different but if you look at spark's `BitmapImage.as` and MX's `SWFLoader.as` closely, you might be able to spot a difference in how they do scaling/smoothing/etc.

Comment: The high quality smoothing didn´t work, but the part about the SWFLoader seems promising...